# How to restart browser after each test scenario

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am testing a Chrome extension using Cucumber in conjunction with Capybara and Selenium-Webdriver.

My test is very simple:

```
  @chrome_extension
    @javascript
      Scenario: Test1
      Given I open a browser
      And I close the browser
      When I do nothing
      Then nothing happens
```

Where the steps are defined as:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Given /^I open a browser$/ do
  visit 'http://google.com'
  STDERR.puts self
end

Given /^I close the browser$/ do
  page.driver.browser.quit
end

Given /^I do nothing$/ do

end

Given /^nothing happens$/ do

end
```

When I call page.driver.browser.quit, it does quit out of the browser session. But then the following error occurs:

```
Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/webmock-1.7.8/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:90:in `request_with_webmock'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.3.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:73:in `response_for'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.3.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:41:in `request'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.3.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:34:in `call'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.3.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:406:in `raw_execute'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.3.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:384:in `execute'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.3.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:228:in `deleteAllCookies'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.3.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/options.rb:67:in `delete_all_cookies'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:81:in `reset!'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:70:in `reset!'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:87:in `block in reset_sessions!'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:87:in `each'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:87:in `reset_sessions!'
      /Users/rui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@yesware/gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:10:in `After'
```

What is the proper way of restarting the browser after each scenario? I need every test to be as stateless as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added an answer below.  The key is that when you set this up you just need to be sure that your @After hook thoroughly destroys WebDriver driver each time.

Answer (score 1):

Using Watir-webdriver, which is very similiar to selenium.

You can do this by using a hook. Do some research on hooks to get a better understanding, but in your support directory for your project, you would want to create a hook file. I am using ruby and rubymine to run my tests, so in your environment it may be different.

Your hook file might look something like this.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'



Before do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
end


After do
  @browser.close
end
```

Then, before each scenario is ran, it will open an instance of the browser and close the browser when the scenario is done.

Answer (score 1):

Clear cookies and refresh browser in an After hook. For example, I use this in Watir-Webdriver

```
After do |scenario|
  browser.cookies.clear
  browser.refresh
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way of doing this, but I would consider having each scenario in its own rake task and using tags in cucumber, like so:

```
desc "Run scenario 1"
task :scenario_1 do
 cmd = "cucumber --tags @1"
 `#{cmd}`
end`
```

Doing this would accomplish exactly what you're after since Cucumber supports this out of the box with the --tags argument.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted java example.

Capybara is trying to save you work by anticipating what you want to do.  Capybara closes the session after every step.  If you close the browser session explicitly then when capybara tries to clean cookies there is no session to clean.

If you don't want capybara to handle these sorts of things then do it yourself without capybara.

Comment: You can see the above in more detail on my GitHub page [here](https://github.com/mikejramsey56/cuc_jav_webdriver.git).

Comment: From the looks of his error message he's using Ruby. Not sure the Java implementation would help him in this case.